# Discard API in Microsoft Graph for sharepoint gives Unsupported segment type. ODataQuery:

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

We are trying to integrate SPOnline in our product for which we need cancel checkout.
I saw the

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/<siteid>/drive/items/01QLNXZVV4M75S2HYNTBF32HGY3ZZ6MAGT/discard
```

api but it is giving

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Unsupported segment type. ODataQuery: sites/<siteid>/drive/items/01QLNXZVV4M75S2HYNTBF32HGY3ZZ6MAGT/discard",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "a3e5a861-3dd6-47a2-b111-fc9087a07b03",
            "date": "2018-06-08T03:51:30"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way we can cancel a checkout using our code?

Also another issue which I saw was if I checkout file from user "A" in a  different org then a user "B" in another org is not able to see the checkout. It appears in the UI but the api ?select=publication gives status published to user B? Is it as designed or an issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you got `/discard` from but there is no such endpoint in Microsoft Graph.

You can revert a file to a previous version using [`/restoreVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitemversion_restore) but there is currently not a method to simply "undo" or "discard" a [`/checkout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_checkout). You would need to `/checkin` in order to unlock the file and then `restoreVersion` to back out any bump in the version number.

Comment: Hello Marc, Thanks for the reply but this would show in the version history of the item ? Is there a way to delete a version entry from version history?

Comment: I'm afraid not.

Comment: Marc, it seems that the Microsoft Graph still does not let us discard a check-out. I added an idea to the [Microsoft Graph User Voice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/40906267-add-an-api-to-discard-a-checkout) but wanted to ask whether you have any idea as to whether this has any chance of being implemented.

Comment: I'm not on the OneDrive team so I'm afraid I can't really speak to their current planning. I can however confirm that UserVoice is actively monitored.

Comment: Yep, and this voice doesn't exist anymore

Comment: To delete a previous file send a "DELETE" Method on the Version:  /drives/[DRIVE ID]/items/[ITEM ID]/versions/[VERION]